# Option for specifying Spark environment API when using Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark

Is there an option you can pass to the spark-shell that specifies what environment you will be running your code against?  In other words, if I am using Spark 1.3; can I specify that I wish to use the Spark 1.2 API ?

For example:

> pyspark --api 1.2

Comment: seems not possible, at least i didnt heard this before for scala api

Answer (score 2):

`spark-shell` initializes [org.apache.spark.repl.Main](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/16687651f05bde8ff2e2fcef100383168958bf7f/repl/scala-2.11/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/repl/Main.scala) to start REPL, which does not parse any command line arguments. Hence no it will not be possible to pass api value from command line, you have use respective `spark-shell` binary from their respective versions of spark.